# Why do we use different phrases for different prophets?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets, salawat

I would like to know the difference between

> salla allah alayhi wa salam,

which we use for the prophet Muhammad and

> aleyhi salam,

which we use for all the other prophets. Why don't we use a single formula for all the prophets?

Answer (score 2):

The salutation صلى الله عليه وسلم can be used with any other prophet. Apparently classical scholars didn't make this distinction. For example, ibn Jarir al-Tabari (d. 310 AH) in his exegesis uses this salutation for:

1. [Hud](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=1&tSoraNo=11&tAyahNo=52&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1)

> لأن هوداً **صلى الله عليه وسلم** إنـما دعا قومه إلـى توحيد الله لـيغفر
>   لهم ذنوبهم

2. [Abraham](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=1&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=258&tDisplay=yes&Page=2&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

> قال إبراهيـم **صلى الله عليه وسلم**: فإن الله الذي هو ربـي يأتـي
>   بـالشمس من مشرقها

3. [Moses](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=1&tTafsirNo=1&tSoraNo=5&tAyahNo=12&tDisplay=yes&Page=3&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

> أمر الله بنـي إسرائيـل أن يسيروا إلـى الأرض الـمقدّسة مع نبـيهم موسى
>   **صلى الله عليه وسلم** فلـما كانوا قريبـاً من الـمدينة

Answer (score -1):

Muhammad Rasulullah was given special gift from Allah, **shalawat**. Allah and angels give shalawat to Muhammad.

We as the ummah also strongly command to give sholawat too.

so that’s why, when we say Muhammad, we say Salla Allahu `alayhi wa salam.

And the other prophet as sunnah teach, we should only say `alayhi salam.

Comment: The question is asking "Why"; just saying it's because that's what the sunnah teaches isn't particularly useful without references.